# Convert dollar amount into word in azure data factory

Tags: python, pandas, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I want to convert transaction amount into words eg $345.67 to Three Hundred forty five point sixty seven in azure data factory.

How can we acheive this.

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda function with `number_to_words` from [`inflect`](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['$345.67','$90.56', '$890']})

import inflect
p = inflect.engine()
df['new'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: p.number_to_words(x, decimal="point"))
print (df)
       col                                           new
0  $345.67  three hundred and forty-five point six seven
1   $90.56                         ninety point five six
2     $890                      eight hundred and ninety
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, but I want to do with Azure Data Factory

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV - there is no possible import python lib?

Comment: to write python code in ADF, we require Custom Activity and that requires Batch Service, VM, Pool. It requires a lot of resource for single requirement. Thatswhy I want to use only ADF or Azure Function to write Python code but not sure how to use Azure Function using Python

Comment: Data Factory doesn't natively work on the row level data, so you'll need to leverage a different service from within the pipeline. A Data Flow activity is your best option for row-level operations.